# Swifit (my first program) catching user input

Tags: swift

I can't figure out how the value of  a.sucess and a.attempt will come from the 
 input of the user writing numbers in the success and attempt box.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Attempts: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Sucess: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Check: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thepage: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func Check(sender: UIButton) {

    var str = "here"

    class Tries {

        var Attempts:Float64 = 100.00
        var Sucess:Float64 = 50.00
        init()  {

        }

        func Shot() {


            if Attempts < 99.5  {
                print ("you need more attempts :( Shoot some more!!")
            }




            else if Attempts > 99 && Sucess > 49 && Sucess / Attempts > 0.4999
            {


                print("accepted")
            } else {
                print("failed ")
            }
        }
    }

    var a = Tries()

    a.Attempts = 200 // this input should come from the user writing input in      the textfield... (NEED HELP HERE)
    a.Sucess = 100 // this input should come from the user writing input in the textfield... (NEED HELP HERE)
    a.Shot() // This is the function that should load when you click on the button: click
```

}

I want a.Attempts and a.Sucess to get the value from the user writing his/Her own numbers in the two boxes.

Comment: Isn't it the same as your previous question? You've accepted an answer over there about Floats and TextLabels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a very bad style of writing code. What you wrote is very difficult to read. Call variables clearer and do not call objects with a capital letter, it need call the names indicate the type and not the names of the objects. Reed this for example: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide to make your code more clear.
About you problem. Maybe I did not quite understand the question, but apparently you just have to read the value of the `UITextField` object and you can do it like:

```
let strValue = textField.text  // in your case Attempts.text
```

then you need to convert it to `CGFloat`:

```
let floatValue = CGFloat((strValue as NSString).floatValue)
```

and then you can use it in your object:

```
a.Attempts = floatValue
```

You should still check that the conversion went well and only then assign a value.

You can do this for example to solve you problem:

```
import UIKit

class ValuesChecker {

    class func checkValues(firstValue: Float, secondValue: Float) -> String {
        if firstValue < 99.5  {
            return "you need more attempts :( Shoot some more!!"
        } else if firstValue > 99 && secondValue > 49 && secondValue / firstValue > 0.4999 {
            return "accepted"
        } else {
            return "failed "
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func actionWithPressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let firstValue = (firstTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
        let secondValue = (secondTextField.text as NSString).floatValue

        println(ValuesChecker.checkValues(firstValue, secondValue: secondValue))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comments:

1. You dont need to create class object in your case. You can create static class method like `checkValues`
2. Instead of a `String` you can give out test results in any way, and use it later in the program

Comment: Why `CGFloat`? No need, just use `(strValue as NSString).floatValue`.

Comment: @alex_P I really appreciate this, never gotten closer to understand how to this than now. However (I just started with swift and programming general, thats why my style is bad too), so the only problem now is, I'm not sure where I should implement my code:    let strValue = Attempts.text

I get decarations error at the moment..

Comment: @Frederic Explain again. You have 2 `textField` and the button and you need to keep the value of `textField` by pressing the button and do some tests. Is it correct?

Comment: @alex_p I have two textfield and one button. A user will type in a value in each textfield. When you press the button, the program should check if the value the user has entered is matching the criteria I have set with my "if" codes.

Comment: @alex_p It works! Sorry it took me song long. I just started and I didnt understand some rookie things, like I had to give my other box another name or it would conflict with the other one etc..

THANK YOU! (note: I have given you a like but since I'm new I don't think it will show)