# Input and Output

Tags: swift, input, printing

I have a textfield and a button. 
When the user enter a number in my textfield and click the button, my program will print a sentence. I can see my print in Xcode, but it doesnt come up on the app screen itself.

Which code is needed to show my the print on the app itself and not only in Xcode's "output section".

Comment: Watch a tutorial on labels: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ETjo1PaQbI

Comment: that video did not help me, because I still need to know what kind of code is needed to connect my print from my "if" sentence to a label.

Comment: Show us your code. We don't know what your "if sentence" looks like. Stack Overflow is for helping with code problems, not writing code for you, or giving advice...

Comment: You need to create label 'UILabel' at your storyboard and make outlet like you made it with your 'UITextfield' , then in code when you need view result make 'label.text = value'

Comment: Alex_p, I have created an UIlabel, and I also thought I had to write 'label.text = value'
But what if its a string and not a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s looks like the continuation of your previous question: [Swifit (my first program) catching user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366533/swifit-my-first-program-catching-user-input/33367255#33367255)

In  this case you need do somthing like this:

```
class ValuesChecker {

    class func checkValues(firstValue: Float, secondValue: Float) -> String {
        if firstValue < 99.5  {
            return "you need more attempts :( Shoot some more!!"
        } else if firstValue > 99 && secondValue > 49 && secondValue / firstValue > 0.4999 {
            return "accepted"
        } else {
            return "failed "
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Add this outlet and make connection from storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func actionWithPressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let firstValue = (firstTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
        let secondValue = (secondTextField.text as NSString).floatValue

        // text to your label
        label.text = ValuesChecker.checkValues(firstValue, secondValue: secondValue)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```